# How to access slider menu from another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, slider

Hi I am working with android applications.I have a slider menu in my library project.I had integrated it with another project and I need to access the same slider menu in my new project.I tried with calling intent, but it calls the full activity.I need only slider menu from the library. How can I access this, please help me.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please give complete detail

Comment: I had created an app with slider menu and make it as a library project.Now I integrated a new project it with it and i want to access the slider menu from the library to my new project.Is there anyway to access this ???

Comment: n circular way you cant use project in library ,you need to create another project which can access these project in single place.

Comment: i already created a library project.Now i can access the activities of project library via intent.